# How do I make changing any of 4 variables change 3 others?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, user-controls, user-input

I have 4 variables that I would link to let user link together for fast adjusting like this:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsEqN.png)

This is how I made linking 2 working like this:

```
bool lockLeft, lockTop, lockRight, lockBottom;

if (lockLeft)
{
    if (radius.topLeft!= oldRadius.topLeft))
        radius.bottomLeft = radius.topLeft;
    if (radius.bottomLeft!= oldRadius.bottomLeft))
        radius.topLeft = radius.
}

//if(lockRight)...similar

oldRadius=radius;
```

The problem is this only work in the order it was coded.

For example, if I compare `topLeft` and `bottomLeft` first, then `topLeft` and `topRight`, then if the user change `topRight` then `bottomLeft` will not be updated, unless I compare `topLeft` and `bottomLeft` again.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: According to your screenshot the user can link together any of them? Like e.g. only the top two and the bottom two or e.g. all of them?

Comment: When do you execute the above code? Directly when you change a field or in an update that runs continuously?

Comment: I want to give the user the choice to link any pair they like, like only top / top and bottom/ top bottom left/ all 4.

Comment: The code is execute whenever the user edit the text field

Comment: How are those values organized? I think an update-chain (or rather two, one clockwise, one counterclockwise) would be the way to go. Something like `if(isConnectedClockwise) neighbor.UpdateClockwise(newVal)` would be possible. That neighbor would then check if the value is already the same (= stop/return) or set it otherwise and check if it also has a connection clockwise. The same for the counterclockwise (the value check prevents an infinite loop).

Comment: That sounds like an interesting solution, I will try to implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have`serializedObject.Update();` at the top of your `OnInspectorGUI()` method

Comment: That isn't relevance here. What I need is some way to lock 4 variable together, not about display them in the editor

Answer (score 0):

Try 2 arrays - one of values and one of bools and then you can check recursively in two directions for linking between values.